# Create a Spacy pipeline with my own Tokeniser?

Tags: spacy

What puzzles me is that a spacy "pipeline" is a sequence of processing steps, but the very first step which converts the original data into a spacy document is "hidden". Unlike all the other steps it cannot be accessed from the pipeline, I think. 
So what if I want to replace it, change it, or create a pipeline with my own Tokenizer, what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the tokenizer isn't part of the regular pipeline is because it's "special": There can only really be one, and while all other pipeline components take a `Doc` and return it, the tokenizer takes a **string of text** and turns it into a `Doc`.

However, `nlp.tokenizer` is writable, so you can either create your own [`Tokenizer` class from scratch](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers), or even replace it with an [entirely custom function](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#custom-tokenizer). Here's a super simple example that shows the idea:

```py
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.tokens import Doc

nlp = English()

def my_tokenizer(text): 
    tokens = text.split(" ")
    doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=tokens)
    return doc

nlp.tokenizer = my_tokenizer
doc = nlp("Hello world!")
print([token.text for token in doc])  # ['Hello', 'world!']
```